# Configure portainer with Minikube's docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-toolbox, minikube

Is there a way to configure Portainer's dashboard to show Minikube's docker?

**Portainer**

Installed in the local docker (toolbox), on VM under windows 7;
the dashboard connection to the local (inside) docker is working fine.

`docker run -d -p 9000:9000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock portainer/portainer`

**Minikube**

Installed in another VM on the same machine with a different port.

- I've created a new Portainer Endpoint using the portainer UI
- Set the Endpoint URL (minikubeIp:2375)
- Selected TLS and point to the path of the cert files

`c:/users/<myusername>/.minikube/certs`

but keep getting an error on the dashboard tab:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)

I'm getting the same error also when configuring the Endpoint *without* TLS.

Is it *possible* to configure Portainer to work with Minikube's Docker?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the Docker API is exposed in the Minikube configuration?

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)

This error is generally raised when Portainer cannot proxy requests to the Docker API.

A simple way to verify that would be to use the Docker CLI and check if Minikube's Docker API is exposed:

`docker -H minikubeIp:2375 info`

If this is returning a connection error, that means that the Docker API is not exposed and thus, Portainer will not be able to connect to it.

Comment: using the minikubeIp:2375 is returning connection error, but 2376 is failed with verify the certificate. so after changing it to 2376 it's working! ? **BUT** i'm getting endless loop of >"Unable to retrieve stats, Is this container running?"

Comment: So, are you able to connect Portainer to the Minikube Docker endpoint using port 2376 and the TLS certs?

Comment: exactly, the certs are taken from the. minikube\certs

Comment: Well it looks like this is running. If you have any troubles, you can join Portainer support on Slack or Gitter.